# Separate base64 images received in HttpResponse

Tags: httpresponse, base64

I am receiving a bunch of images together in base64 format in a HttpResponse. I am querying my java heroku app which returns a response something like this:

[imgData]{base64image}[/imgData]/n
[imgData]{base64image}[/imgData]

I add the [imgData] and [/imgData] tags in my java class to separate the base64 image data from each other and the new line character separate each image.

In my apex class I am doing something like this:

```
        String images = response.getBody();
        String[] imageArray = image.split('/n');
        Integer imageCount = 0;
        List<String> base64Values = new List<String>();
        for(String base64Img : imageArray) {
            base64Values.add(base64Img.subStringBetween('[imgData]', '[/imgData]').trim());
        }
```

I need to use this list and generate attachments from these images.

Now the base64 value of a single image is pretty large, so large that I cant even paste here to show you guys.

Now my problem is when my apex class runs, I expect it to split the large string and then just save the base64 encoded value in the list.

But it gives me System.LimitException: Regex too complicated error.

Any idea on how I can extract the base64 from that large response? Or should I just change the way I am sending the values to the apex class from heroku?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got up to 6M bytes of heap to play with (and I think a maximum HTTP body size of 3M bytes) so if say the base64 version of all the images is always smaller than say a couple of Mbytes then sending them all at once should be OK.

String has an [indexOf](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_string.htm#apex_System_String_indexOfChar_2) method that you could use to work through each block of base64 in turn first finding a '[imgData]' and then the following '[/imgData]' and using [substring](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_string.htm#apex_System_String_substring_2) you can pull out the text in between without hitting the regex problem.

Answer (score 1):

Using the method that Keith C suggested.

```
        String media = '[img]john[/img][img]jill[/img][img]jack[/img][img]judy[/img][img]jamie[/img][img]james[/img][img]johnny[/img]';
        Integer first = 0; 
        Integer last = 0;
        Integer lastOccurrence = media.lastIndexOf('[/img]');
        while(true) {
            first = media.indexOf('[img]', last);
            last = media.indexOf('[/img]', first);
            System.debug('first : ' + first);
            System.debug('last : ' + last);
            String substring = media.substring(first + 5, last);
            System.debug('substring : ' + substring);
            if(last == lastOccurrence) {
                break;
            }
        }
```